# Deploying a .NET 4.5 RESTful API to IIS 10

Tags: iis

I have developed an ASP.NET Web Service in Visual Studio 2013. The target framework is .NET 4.5.

I am attempting to deploy the Web Service in IIS 10 running on a Windows Server 2016. I have registered.NET 4.5 on the IIS using the following command - ***dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:IIS-ASPNET45***.

I have also enabled 32-bit applications in the application pool.

I have also ensured that .NET extensibility for .NET 4.6 and ASP.NET 4.6 are enabled, in the application development features.

I am getting the following error when trying to browse the web service - ***HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden The Web Server is Configured to Not List the Contents of this Directory***.

[image]

The funny thing is that when I deploy the web service to IIS 8, it runs with no problem at all.

I am at my wits' end. Could someone please tell me where I am going wrong with the IIS 10?

Comment: I suggest you could firstly check you have use the right url, maybe the web api doesn't have the default page. Besides, I suggest you could check the IIS web site folder to make sure you have published the file into right folder.

Comment: @BrandoZhang, I am browsing directly from IIS. Right click on the site -> Manage -> Browse. Further to that, I have deployed the api to IIS 8 and it runs without any issues whatsoever.